# Cell decomposition of non-orientable surfaces

Tags: general-topology, non-orientable-surfaces

I saw that a cell-decomposition of a genus g non-orientable surface is $D^0\cup D^1\cup ...\cup D^g$. Can anyone explain why this is true?

Comment: I think you are confusing two things. The simplest cell-decomposition for a genus 1 nonorientable surface has three cells, a $0$-cell, a $1$-cell and a $2$cell, which doesn't match your count. What you have written looks instead like a cell decomposition for $\mathbb{RP}^g$, or projective $g$-space. (The $g$-dimensional projective plane.)

Comment: Oh yeah. That's why it didn't make sense to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Grumpy Parsnip pointed out, the decomposition fits $g$-dimensional real projective space (listed among examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex#Examples)), not a surface. A surface can't have cells of dimension more than $2$.

A non-orientable closed surface of genus $g$ can be constructed out of one $0$-cell, $g$ $1$-cells, and one $2$-cell. ([Reference](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/2-manifolds))